# Click Event in Python 2.7

Tags: python

I have python 2.7 running on google app engine, and I am trying to create a click event using html. I have no idea how to do this. any help would be appreciated. here is my html code.

```
body = '''
    <button id='b'>I'm a button</button>'''
```

Comment: Surely there are examples regarding google found with google

Comment: not that I can find :/

Comment: ummm... a search for [html click event](https://www.google.com/#q=html+click+event) yields 313 million results, with the first one being the link referenced in David Zemens' answer below. [onclick script example](https://www.google.com/#q=onclick+script+example) brings up 4 million hits...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Call a python function within a html file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5615228/call-a-python-function-within-a-html-file)

Comment: Question could benefit from clarification, it is not clear what OP is trying to do. The obvious problem is answered by `onClick` attribute, as it appears OP is creating HTML from a py script...

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the `onClick` attribute to execute a javascript function when clicked.  This is reasonably well-documented and you should be able to find examples using any search engine.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ev_onclick.asp

```
<element onclick="script">
```

In your case, perhaps:

```
script = "myFunction()" 
body = "<button id='b' onclick='" + script + "'>I'm a button</button>"
```

**Note** this assumes you're using a python script to create the HTML which will render the page(s).  The solution (without more detail/clarification) is obviously the `onClick` attribute, but that calls a javascript function.

If you need to call python function, see this link on SO:

[Call a python function within a html file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5615228/call-a-python-function-within-a-html-file)

Comment: No! I'm looking to do it in python. I already know how to do that with JS.

Comment: See revision and link to similar question, wherein you can probably find a suitable answer.