# .py file execution issues

Tags: python, html

I am trying to execute a `.py` file in html, but when i run the .py file it simply comes up as the source code.

Is it possible to import and execute a .py file from the html code. I have tried using `<a href="___.py"></a>` but when I click on the url it just brings up the source code of the .py file.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Call a python function within a html file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5615228/call-a-python-function-within-a-html-file)

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to directly execute a python file from HTML.

Here are some alternatives:

You could use a python-in-browser implementation like Skulpt (http://www.skulpt.org/)

You could use PHP. (If you're on ubuntu or similar, sudo apt-get install apache2 php)

```
<?php
echo shell_exec('python ___.py');
?>
```

You could try using a python-enabled web-server like Tornado (http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/)

Comment: @LeytonTaylor Brython is also available (http://www.brython.info/) but I haven't tried it before.