# Calling a python function with a button

Tags: python, flask

I want to be able to click on a button in html and call a python function.
I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5615228/call-a-python-function-within-a-html-file) and it works but only for text. And I have seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11556958/sending-data-from-html-form-to-a-python-script-in-flask) that you can use the function name in action for buttons but it does not work and I dont know why :/

And I dont want after the click of the button go to to another page, I want to stay on the same page and just execute the code from the function.

my py file :

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
import sys
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return render_template('hello.html')

@app.route('/upload/')
def uploaduj():
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.withdraw()
    file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    return file_path
```

my html file:

```
<!doctype html> 
<title>Flaskr</title> 
<link rel=stylesheet type=text/css href="{{ url_for('static', filename='style.css') }}"> 
<div class=page>   
<h1>Flaskr</h1>   
<div class=metanav>   
<button action="/upload/">Klik</button> 
</div>
```

I am really new to python and flask so every help is appreciated.

**EDIT:** i now know that tkinter will not work in web browsers

Comment: You can't open tkinter windows in the browser, can you?

Comment: I can, that part works perfectly

Comment: Really? It looks like you're making the server open a file dialog. This shouldn't work if the server is on another computer

Comment: ooooh :( I didnt know that, the server and the computer I am testing it on are the same so I didnt even think about that, thank you , i will have to research this

Comment: Use `<input type='file'>`. Tk is a GUI library. Even if you get it to work it wouldn't be a part of the browser.

Comment: @MilosRadosavljevic TkInter is NOT a web UI library. It is not meant to be used with web applications. It might _appear_ to work in your case, but actually it will never work with web applications. Also, is `action` a custom attribute you are trying to attach to `button`, because `button` elements do not have an `action` attribute.

Comment: Name your methods in english, not Czech :P

Comment: @kemis Yeah... Slavic languages :D I will delete my comments soon. It is very unprofessional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want an HTML file input dialog.

```
<form action="/upload">
    <input type="file" name="fileupload" value="fileupload" id="fileupload">
    <label for="fileupload"> Select a file to upload</label>
    <input type="submit" value="Klik">
</form>
```

How you handle that in Flask, [is in the documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/latest/patterns/fileuploads/)

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
<button action="{{ url_for('uploaduj') }}">Klik</button>
```

or just use a tag:

```
<a href="{{ url_for('uploaduj') }}">Klik</a>
```

To avoid page redirect, you can use this :

```
return (''), 204
```

Comment: The first one does not work and the second one is like the one I said in my question that worked but I want it to be a button. The redirect works so you get +1 :D
I put the button in a form and used action there and it works now, a little stupid but works, thank you

Comment: You can use CSS to style it.