# How to run a python script from html

Tags: html, python-3.x, raspberry-pi

I have been trying to run a python script (`rainbow.py`) through a HTML button. I have no idea how to do this and all the answers I have found make no sense to me. All I want is a simple explanation of how to run a python script through regular HTML script.

I am trying to do this on a Raspberry Pi.

Comment: What kind of http server do you use?

Comment: Include more in your post (code) and maybe you want a [framework](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5615268/5645103)

Answer (score 2):

You can make it through [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org), a **Python Web Microframework**:

HTML (index.html):

```
<a href="{{ url_for('do_something') }}">Your button</a>
```

Python (app.py):

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    # render your html template
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/something')
def do_something():
    # when the button was clicked, 
    # the code below will be execute.
    print 'do something here'
    ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Start the server:`$ python app.py`

Then go to http://127.0.0.1:5000.

File structure:

```
template\  
    -index.html  
app.py
```